# can't log in to Snapchat - Problem connecting to the server

Tags: snapchat

Firstly, apologies if this is the wrong site to ask this question. I didn't have a clue which site, this seemed most realistic.

Problem :

Snapchat was working fine. I logged out of my account and when I try log back in I get the error: There was a problem connecting to the server. Please try again.

I have tried multiple solutions such as clearing the cache snapchat, reinstalling google play services, clearing data on snapchat, rebooting device. None of which work.

You might say why not reinstall snapchat? Well my device is on 4.1.2 meaning if I uninstall and go back to the play store to reinstall it, I wont see snapchat there because snapchat has updated further than my phones version.  (I don't have the filters on my device because it doesnt support the filters too)

I tried contacting snapchat, but alas, no reply.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138088/discussion-on-question-by-grand-skunk-cant-log-in-to-snapchat-problem-connect).