# can't use instagram's 'boomerang'

Tags: instagram

I downloaded 'boomerang' and I pressed the button to take a video but then it said ' something went wrong please try again'. I have reinstalled this app, but still got this problem. I have also been having an issue with logging in to snapchat, here [can't log in to Snapchat - Problem connecting to the server](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201730/cant-log-in-to-snapchat-problem-connecting-to-the-server?noredirect=1#comment257911_201730)

would this be a problem? is there something wrong with my phone? should I consider factory resetting  my phone??

Comment: well I just factory resetted my device. didn't have much on it. home it works

Answer (score -1):

For login to snapchat use VPN maybe your problem is fixed.